# WPF drag cursor in default cursors

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, mouse-cursor

I'd like to use the default drag mouse cursor on mouse-over a UIElement to indicate a control is draggable.

The cursor that looks like an arrow and a FocusVisual rectangle with an overlapping plus sign inside a rectangle. Basically, the cursor that is used when setting DragDropEffects.Copy during a drag operation.

However I'd like to use this cursor like all the other types by using something like Cursor="DragCopy". Unfortunately it seems this cursor isn't available. I don't want to use a custom cursor because of compatibility and visual standards between OS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to p/invoke the [SetCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393.aspx) Win32 method.